# Displaying JavaScript Hidden Elements in Other Location on Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**Update: I have changed my JavaScript code, and I am now receiving errors in my iPhone Debug Console.**

**Disclaimer**: I'm new to web development, and I'm not too good with JavaScript.

**Scenario**: I'm building an event calendar with CodeIgniter, and I'm hiding elements on mobile devices that need to be displayed elsewhere on the page when an event occurs. The elements being hidden are `<ul>`s, and they need to be displayed on another portion of the page when their cooresponding `<span>`s with the class `.day_listing_mobile` are selected. I've been working with different methods, but I haven't been able to find a solution out for hours as I'm not strong in the realm of jQuery/Ajax/JavaScript.

**Question**: What methods would be required to make the hidden `<ul>`s be displayed on a different portion of the page when their corresponding `<span>`s are selected?

**JavaScript (Updated)**:

```
(function($) {
    var isMobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
    if (isMobile) {
        $('.event_list').hide(); // setting display:none; on all .event_list <ul> elements

        // attach click event to the <span class="day_listing"> elements
        $('.day_listing_mobile').click(function() {
            var eventList = $(this).sibling('.event_list').clone();
            $(this).sibling('.event_list').remove();
            $('#mobile_show_content').append(eventList);
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

**I'm Receiving this error on this line of code `var $eventList = $(this).sibling('.event_list').clone();`** :

[image: Debug Console - iPhone]

**CodeIgniter Calendar Template (Controller)**:

```
            {cal_cell_content}      
                <span class="day_listing_mobile">
                    {day}
                </span>
                <ul class="event_list">
                    {content}       
                </ul>
            {/cal_cell_content}

            {cal_cell_content_today}
                <span class="day_listing_mobile" id="today_listing">
                    {day}
                </span>
                <ul class="event_list">
                    {content}   
                </ul>
            {/cal_cell_content_today}
```

**View**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <?php echo $calendar; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show-on-phones">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns" id="mobile_show_content">
           <!--I want the <ul>s to show up here-->  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the CodeIgniter calendar class generates above where I want to display the `<ul>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your `click` event to move the data around the dom.

```
  $('.day_listing_mobile').click(function() {
            var eventList = $(this).sibling('.event_list').clone();
            $(this).sibling('.event_list').remove();
            $('.mobile_show_content').append(eventList);
        });
```

Comment: This is the example I was starting to write in response to your comment. Turn on JS debugging on your phone and look at the error. But really, user-agent detection is a really bad idea and you should be looking how to use css-selectors to reflow your page based on the width of the client window and not force mobile phones to be different.  safari on your phone has the same css/js/html parser/renderer as on the desktop, treat it as such.

Comment: Receiving this error (JavaScript: Error undefined TypeError: 'undefined'is not a function) on this line of code var $eventList = $(this).sibling('.event_list').clone(); Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the node from the DOM and re-append it in a different place. (.remove() and .append())

But, rather than trying to solve this in javascript, why not design your page with adaptability in mind using css selectors to reflow the page at certain view port widths.

Check this out:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: BTW - you don't have to remove the element before you append it - if you append() a element that is currently in the dom to some other location, then it moves that element.

Comment: Ok, I turned on my debugger, and when I select the `<span>`s with a class of `.day_listing_mobile` the error reads as follows. `JavaScript: Error undefined TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function`

Comment: can you update your question with the code that you wrote and a pointer to the line that is broken?

Comment: Receiving this error (JavaScript: Error undefined TypeError: 'undefined'is not a function) on this line of code var $eventList = $(this).sibling('.event_list').clone(); Any thoughts?